# returning JSON Array in Node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

Im still trying to get my head around the asynchronous flow in Node. Im trying to read list of files in db and convert result to json array and return back. The code works fine for one json object. But there is no output when reading the complete array

So this is the code

Function call - receive ajax request from browser and send back result

```
module.retrieveSourceContent(req, res, result, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                  console.log(err);
                  return;
                }
                console.log(result);
                res.contentType('json');
                res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
                res.end();
            });
```

Code

```
 retrieveSourceContent : function(req, res, sourceList, callback){
        var sourceContent = new Array();
        MongoClient.connect(config.mongoPath+config.dbName, function(err, db) {
           if(err){
             return callback(new Error("Unable to Connect to DB"));
           }
           var collection = db.collection(config.source);
           for( i=0;i<sourceList['sources_FOR'].length;i++){
              //build the source JSON Array
              collection.find({'_id':sourceList['sources_FOR'][i]}).nextObject(function(err, doc) {
                if(err)
                  return callback(new Error("Error finding data in DB"));
                    var sourceObject = {
                        title     :doc.name,
                        tagCount  :doc.tag.length,
                        tags      :doc.tag,       
                        format    :doc.type,     // Differentiate text, image, video and urls
                        content   :doc.data      // Content
                    };
                    sourceContent.push(sourceObject);
                    //if(i == sourceList['sources_FOR'].length - 1)
                      return callback(null, sourceContent);

              });
           }
        });
      }
```

This code return one json object to client. If i uncomment `if(i == sourceList['sources_FOR'].length - 1)` i have no output and no error. But `sourceContent.push(sourceObject);` does create the json array successfully.

Since this flow works on other language, i suspect it has something to do with asyn flow of node. Im at a loss here on how to solve this.

Any help would be great..

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit difficult following the flow of the program due to the formatting. But I think you are correct assuming that this has to do with async behaviour. If I'm not fooled by the formatting, it looks to me like you're doing the callback in every iteration of the loop, which would only work for the first iteration. I'm not sure what your `sourcesList` is, but I would try to construct a query that includes all the items in `sourcesList`. Then you would not need the foor loop. Maybe you can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) operator.

Comment: Hi Nilsh, Sorry about the formatting. Tried to keep the code small as possible. Yes, im doing call back every iteration, Since the call back does not work outside the loop. So used if-condition to check end of loop, that is where the code stops working. `SourceList` is an large array of IDs from one table, which i use to extract data from another table in JSON array and display to client. Yes, looking into changing the entire query now.

Comment: The reason it stops working is that you have to invoke the callback for the flow to continue. So when you're not invoking the callback within `find`, it'll just wait forever. There are solutions to this (synchronization of callbacks), for instance using a flow library (which there are multiple options for), but in this case, I think you'd be better off fixing your query so the loop is not required.